# how to NOT open files in webstorm 9 project explorer?

Tags: windows, webstorm

I cant figure out how to turn this feature off in webstorm 9 in windows 7:
When I am in the project explorer and click on a file so not doubleclick, it still opens the file . How can I turn this off so it only opens a file when I doubleclick on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deactivate **Autoscroll to Source** option (menu under cogs icon .. or right click on tool window header/title)

[image]